# How to compare two different rows of two different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im having two different tables Value(queid, m) and Ans(queid1, an). I want to compare queid and queid1 and if they are same then m and an's values and has to update the third table with correct values.  Thanx a tons. 
 Table structures are 
 Value table  will have two attributes queid and m. queid will have data like 3, 4, 5, 6, and m will have a, v, d, e
 Ans table will have attributes queid1 and an. queid1 attributes will have data like 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4 and an will have data like a, v, a, a, a, c, e, r, e, d. 
 Now what i want is that it should compare the values of queid with queid1. so if we consider **3** ie first value of queid in value table, then it should find all the **3's** in  **ans** table and then is should compare **a** (ie the row corresponding to 3 in value table) with all the **3's** in ans. And the corresponding right comparison of **a**'s is to be stored in some third table.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question, but I'll take a shot:

```
   Update PsychiciallyDiscernedThirdTable
      set m=b.m, an=c.an
     from value b
     join ans c
       on b.queid=c.queid1
```